# How to attach callback to jquery effect on dialog show?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, callback, effects

My problem is that I do not know how to attach callback to the jquery ui dialog show.

The show is actually an option:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: 'slide' });
```

I want to have a callback after the slide animation is complete. I looked from the effects itself and they have a callback:

```
effect( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )
```

But in the dialog the effect is set up very differently. I tried also putting:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: 'slide', callback: function() {} });
```

But it didn't work.

Suggestions?

Comment: what about the open event ? http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open This event is triggered when dialog is opened.
Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the open event as an init option.

    $( ".selector" ).dialog({
       open: function(event, ui) { ... }
    });

Comment: @max4ever: `open` will fire when the dialog opens, the OP wants to be notified when the animation has stopped.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update 2015-07-27** For anyone using jQuery v1.10.0 or above please see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18257205/637889) as my solution will not work with newer versions of jQuery.

---

**Original answer**

Already answered but since I had an answer, I'm going to post it anyway…

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    show: {
        effect: 'slide',
        complete: function() {
            console.log('animation complete');
        }
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('open');
    }
});
```

Shows `open` followed by `animation complete` in the *Console*

Comment: I'll just also accept your answer because it wouldn't be any profit for myself to just accept my own answer.

Comment: Heh, thanks. Honestly wasn't posting it for points. I had literally just pasted my answer in after digging through the code myself :-)

Comment: Sadly, this does not work anymore since version 1.10.x. http://jsbin.com/obuza3/50/edit

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll take a look over the next couple of days.

Comment: I already found a solution a few days ago, check my answer below.

Comment: Please edit your answer to reflect that it will not work past 1.10.x.

Comment: @VaelVictus anyone with enough rep can edit my answer, which is actively encouraged by SO. I'll edit it this time though since you asked nicely :D

Comment: Well, gee, thanks for the downvote with no explanation

Comment: What string would I use for effect if I don't actually want an effect, just whatever it would do without the "show" option?

Comment: @Andrew it might be better to ask a new question with a working example of your problem. My answer has been superseded as the jQueryUI code has moved on. I believe the effect is a required parameter when supplying show with an Object value. The modern answer below has hooked into the `promise().done` directly in the `open` function and would not require any non-default configuration of the `show` function which may be what you need.

Answer (score 37):

Two years later, the suggested solution (by @andyb) is no longer working in current versions of jQuery UI (specifically since v1.10.0). His solution relied on the `complete` callback method - an undocumented feature .

I've came up with an up-to-date solution, using jQuery [`Promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) object:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    show: {
        effect: "drop",
        direction: "up",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "drop",
        direction: "down",
        duration: 1000
    },
    open: function () {
        $(this).parent().promise().done(function () {
            console.log("[#Dialog] Opened");
        });
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).parent().promise().done(function () {
            console.log("[#Dialog] Closed");
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the usual JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/jcmpm/

Comment: Do you mean the opposite? I didn't use `when().done`. Anyway, it ultimately returns a `Promise` object so I don't see the benefit, just extra overhead.

Comment: In September 2014, this is perfect.

Comment: This doesn't seem to wait until after a "delay" with show. OR, really what's at issue with my code is when I put in the "show:", the code I have to change the button focus in the dialog (now put in the above open: callback, no longer works).

Comment: `$(this).parent()` can be replaced with `$(this).dialog('widget')`

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the jquery ui dev bundle and found out that the callback is set with "complete":

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: 'slide', complete: function() {} });
```

Thanks for everyone trying to help solve this :)

Comment: Damn, I was literally about to write that!

Comment: I am not getting the "complete:" callback.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `open` event of dialog:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: This will not solve it unfortunately. The OP wants a callback when the animation has finished. Try changing the animation to a longer one like `shake` and note that the `open` callback is fired at the beginning of the animation, not the end.

Answer (score 0):

I found it necessary to use the "focus:" event. I was losing the correctly selected button because of the show:. Lovely interactions.

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('Upload')").focus();
},
```

Comment: But, this is less than perfect, as the change in focus (from one of my buttons to the other) is visibly noticeable. :(.