# Animation Complete Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have encountered a issue with the UI dialog. I hooked into the complete event to create a TinyMCE since it does not play nice with the animations. But it does not seem to be working in the latest version of JQuery UI.

I searched around the release notes to see if this has been changed or anything but I did not see it listed anywhere.

Is this a removed/moved functionality or is this an issue in v1.10.0?

Here is the sample code, used in the jsfiddle below:

```
$("div").dialog({
    show:{
        effect:"puff",
        duration:400,
        complete:function()
        {
            $(".complete").html("Animation Complete.");
        }
    }
});
```

Previous Version Functionality(1.9.2):

http://jsfiddle.net/N4APL/1/

Latest Version Functionality(1.10.0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jXDYz/1/

Note: I used the MS CDN for the UI javascript since jsfiddle does not have it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was quite a journey, but I finally figured out your problem and solution.

Indeed this `complete` feature has been removed from jQuery UI dialog 1.10.0.  [It's not in the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-show).  I'm not sure why it was removed, and they certainly don't have it documented in the upgrade guide.

After some digging into the 1.10.0 code, I found this:

```
this._show( this.uiDialog, this.options.show );
```

As you can see, there is no callback to `._show` (which is just jQuery's `.show`) and no way to set a callback either.  Ack!  You're stuck.

...or you would be were jQuery 1.10.1 not on the way:

```
this._show( this.uiDialog, this.options.show, function() {
    that._focusTabbable();
    that._trigger("focus");
});
```

You still can't set a callback directly, but you can set it via the `focus` option in 1.10.1.  [I have confirmed that this works](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/jXDYz/2/).

I still think this will be quite a bit shaky for others, but at least not for you.  You have the option of either upgrading to jQuery 1.10.1 now or just waiting it out with 1.9 until it comes.

Comment: Thank you for researching this! Looks like the focus is finally doing what I expected it to be doing, waiting for the animation to complete before being fired. I will just use 1.9 until 1.10.1 is stable.

Answer (score 0):

As @brian noted, the `complete` callback feature was removed on v1.10.0, and never added back since than.
Brian's method is neat, however, will only work on `open`.

Here I propose a more correct approach that would work for both `open` and `close`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18257205/2678731

Tested successfully on (latest) v1.10.3: http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/jcmpm/