# event for when dialog is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a jscrollpane to a dialog once the dialog is loaded.  I tried using the `dialogopen` and `dialogfocus` events but it seems these trigger too early.  Is there an event I can subscribe to that tells me the dialog is fully loaded and displayed and its safe to call jscrollpane? Right now i'm just adding a half second timeout but that seems hacky and shows the user a broken dialog for a half second.

Any other solutions would also be welcome.

```
$("#diagBox").load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
        $dialog.imagesLoaded(function() {

            $dialog.dialog('open');
            $dialog.dialog("option", "position", "center");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('input, textarea').placeholder();
                $('.scroller').jScrollPane();
                positionElements();
            },500);


        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle example?

Comment: working on a jsfiddle, might take a while to make it compact enough

Comment: What version of jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: jquery UI version 1.9.2

Comment: Having trouble making the jsfiddle.  As you see my code loads a separate page and I can't do that in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Lumpy I believe that this is a "bug" in jQuery UI 1.9 (or they accidentally removed the feature) that has been restored in jQuery UI 1.10

Comment: @Explosion Pills thanks, this worked.  now to discover all the other bugs this upgrade has created.

Comment: @Lumpy see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741483/animation-complete-dialog