# Javascript not wait file dialog closing

Tags: javascript, file, upload

My problem is javascript not wait for file selection dialog closing.
I have just found an solution that we declare a onChange event for  element. So onChange event work right, but script still run before onChange event. They a asynchronous.
I think may be there is a way to check if there is any dialog opening ?
Please help me, 2 day of mine :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call back method after dialog is completely opened, you can use using jQuery `Promise` object as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18257205/6631053) answer:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    show: {
        effect: "drop",
        direction: "up",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "drop",
        direction: "down",
        duration: 1000
    },
    open: function () {
        $(this).parent().promise().done(function () {
            console.log("[#Dialog] Opened");
        });
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).parent().promise().done(function () {
            console.log("[#Dialog] Closed");
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the usual JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/jcmpm/

Comment: Is it work with file Dialog, I apply the code and then the dialog not appear more :)